# How to solve this error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime "

Tags: asp.net

Hello 
      I am using datetime datatype in sql sever but whenever i save this form i am getting this error "**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime**" . In my code i am using ajax code on textbox to select date . But same error i am getting . I am specify date format into it but still it get error . What we do now.

Comment: You should provide some more information, like more of the error message so that it's possile to determine if it comes from the database or the code preparing the data for the database call, and perhaps some code so that we can see how the data is handled. The data could possibly be converted back and forth between date and string several times before it gets to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try Format:

```
DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this vb code to convert it :

`dataandtimevarible.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`

you need to add Format="dd-MM-yyyy"  to your mark up code and add this one to your markup Code

`<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" TargetControlID="CreatedOnTextBox">
                    </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>`

last thing you have to make sure from the Culture language!!!

Comment: mmmmm. ok .

what is your language??

i had this problem before because the language was Arabic.

Comment: hi finally i got solution on it that where i am taking datetime datatype in place i took nvarchar datatype into my code.but in sql server i took datetime datatype.....

Comment: ha ha ha ha ha...glad to here you found the Issue.

Answer (score 0):

How are you saving your data into the database? Are you using [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter.aspx)? If not then use parameters - to save date/time value, choose your parameter data type as `DbType.DateTime`.

Now, your text box will give you a string value and you need to convert it to date/time data type before assigning to the parameter. Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method with your specific date format - for example,

```
var param = new SqlParameter("MyDateColumn");
param.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
param.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(textbox1.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```